# I'm trying to take names and the amount of groups from a user. Then separate them into groups. Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, chunked

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    
    //receive names from user
    print("Enter the names: ")
    val names = readLine()?.split("/n")

    //receive number of groups from the user
    print("Enter number of groups: ")
    val group = readLine()

    print(names.chunked(group))
}
```

I was trying to print the users into evenly separated groups. I found that I could use chunked to accomplish this. But when I try to input the amount of groups to the chunked function nothing happens. it outputs "kotlin.Unit" I'm guessing this is an error code. But I don't know how I messed up my code.

Comment: The above is not compileable code, so it's not possible to tell what you're doing wrong in your actual code that you were able to run. `kotlin.Unit` is not an error code. It is what any function returns if it doesn't return anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, this code does not compile. It still has the following problems:

1. `names` can be `null`, so you'll either have to ensure that it isn't, which you could do using the Elvis operator:

   ```kotlin
   val names = readLine()?.split("\n") ?: return
   ```

   Or you can use a safe call on `names` wherever you use it:

   ```kotlin
   names?.chunked(group)
   ```
2. If you look at the documentation for [chunked](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/chunked.html), you'll see that it has one parameter, `size` of type `Int`. However, you are passing a `String` to it, which you've read from the user. You'll have to try to convert this string to an int before passing it into chunked:

   ```kotlin
   val group = readLine()?.trim()?.split(" ")?.first()?.toInt() ?: return
   ```

   Note that I'm trimming and splitting the user input to increase chances of retrieving a valid int.

Fixing these problems makes your code compile. However, there's one more thing to fix. Assuming you meant the newline character with `/n`, you are now using the newline character as a separator for the names as well as to indicate that the user is done entering names. I suggest you use something different, like a comma. In total, this could give something like the following.

```kotlin
fun main() {
    //receive names from user
    print("Enter the names (separated by a comma): ")
    val names = readLine()?.split(",")?.map { it.trim() }

    //receive number of groups from the user
    print("Enter number of groups: ")
    val group = readLine()?.trim()?.split(" ")?.firstOrNull()?.toInt() ?: return

    print(names?.chunked(group))
}
```